# Unable to use virtual function in C++ child Class

Tags: c++, c++14, virtual-inheritance

I am making a virtual function program where there are three classes Person, Professor and Student. Person is inherited by both Professor an Student publicly. Here I want to input some parameters in professor and student. To input and output them I have made **getdata** and **putdata** in each class. In person class these functions are defined virtually. But In the code i am having some errorsi.ie -

```
Solution.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Solution.cpp:84:26: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Professor’
             per[i] = new Professor;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
Solution.cpp:20:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Professor’:
 class Professor : public Person
       ^~~~~~~~~
Solution.cpp:16:18: note:   ‘virtual void Person::putdata()’
     virtual void putdata() = 0;
                  ^~~~~~~
Solution.cpp:87:27: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Student’
         else per[i] = new Student; // Else the current object is of type Student
                           ^~~~~~~
Solution.cpp:42:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Student’:
 class Student: public Person
       ^~~~~~~
Solution.cpp:16:18: note:   ‘virtual void Person::putdata()’
     virtual void putdata() = 0;
                  ^~~~~~~
```

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
    string name;
    int age;

    virtual void getdata() = 0;
    virtual void putdata() = 0;

};

class Professor : public Person
{
    public:
    static int cur_id;
    int publications; 

    Professor() {
        cur_id++;
    }

    void getdata( )
    {

        cin>>name>>age>>publications;
    }

    void pushdata()
    {
        cout<<name<<" "<<age<<" "<<publications<<"\n";
    }
};

class Student: public Person
{
    public:
    static int cur_id;
    int marks[6];

    Student(){cur_id++;}

    void getdata()
    {
        cin>>name>>age;
        int i=0;
        for(i = 0;i<6;i++)
          cin>>marks[i];
    }

    void pushdata()
    {
        cout<<name<<" "<<age;

        int i=0,sum=0;
        for(i = 0;i<6;i++)
          sum += marks[i];

        cout<<" "<<sum<<" "<<cur_id;
    }
};

int Professor::cur_id = 1;
int Student::cur_id = 1;
int main(){
```

Comment: `putdata` and `pushdata` aren't the same thing. Good to to learn about the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function:

```
void pushdata()
    {
        cout<<name<<" "<<age<<" "<<publications<<"\n";
    }
```

does *not* override the pure virtual function `putdata` in `Person`.

Instead do:

```
void putdata() override
    {
        cout<<name<<" "<<age<<" "<<publications<<"\n";
    }
```

Note that if you put `override` on the functions you want to override, the compiler will give an error if you make a mistake.